# Android lint not showing errors when minSdkVersion < targetSdkVersion, if targetSdkVersion=23 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, lint, android-6.0-marshmallow

As the question states, I am compiling with SDK 23, targeting SDK 23, and using a min SDK version of 19. Android Studio/Eclipse should show a lint error when using any component from API level 20/21/22/23, however it does not for API level 23.

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.test"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

}

public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Incorrect cast for a system service, correctly caught by lint
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        Fragment fragment = new Fragment();
        fragment.isDetached(); //API level 13 (correct, no warning)
        fragment.setMenuVisibility(true); //API level 14 (correct, no warning)

        finishAndRemoveTask(); //API level 21 (correct, warning)
        getMediaController(); //API level 21 (correct, warning)

        getReferrer(); //API level 22 (correct, warning)

        getSearchEvent(); //API level 23 (INCORRECT: no warning)
        showLockTaskEscapeMessage(); //API level 23 (INCORRECT: no warning)
    }
}
```

I used http://developer.android.com/sdk/api_diff/23/changes.html to pick a few methods to test.

I didn't see any information about this immediately on google, or at http://developer.android.com/tools/help/lint.html, http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I found an open issue at [AOSP Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=183500&q=lint%2023&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars), looks like platforms-23/android.jar is not being included in the apigenerator script. Google is working on a fix.